# Inverse metric in the perturbative approach of General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity

In General Relativity there is a helpful procedure which is called "Perturbative approach".
Given a chart, and forgetting the basis, the metric is $g_{uv}$ and we can express it as: $$g_{uv}=\eta_{uv}+h_{uv}$$
From a physical point of view the explanation it's very simple: $\eta_{uv}$ represents the metric in absence of gravity while $h_{uv}$ are perturbations around it.
Now, one would express Christoffel symbols $\Gamma_{uv}^{\alpha}$ in terms of the perturbation $h_{uv}$ but in order to do it one has to express the inverse metric in terms of $h_{uv}$.
The inverse metric is not $$g^{uv}=\eta^{uv}+h^{uv}$$ otherwise $$g_{u\alpha}g^{\alpha v}\not=\delta_{uv}$$
Now, my question is: what is the expression of $g^{uv}$ in terms of $h^{uv}$?
Be careful: you can' t neglect high powers of $h_{uv}$

Comment: To first order of $h$, three is no problem with the simple definition of the inverse, and in linearised relativity, that's all that matters.

Comment: I am not dealing with Gravitational waves, so I can't neglect high powers of $h_{uv}$. That' s why I need the entire expression of $g^{uv}$ in terms of $h^{uv}$.

Comment: Oh, I misread. You said perturbative, I assumed linearised.